# Bootstrap Popover not working inside bootstrap panel body

Tags: html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am having a simple bootstrap popover and I have placed it inside panel body. It works great when I place popover outside the panel body. But I am not sure why it is not working when I place same popover inside panel body.

**PopOver Inside Panel Body**

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div style="border:1px solid black; margin-top:5px; margin-bottom:5px;">
                    <input id="rbtnTab1" type="radio" name="tabs" checked>
                    <label id="lblTab1" for="rbtnTab1">Tab 1</label>
                    <section id="content1">
                        <div>
                            <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-offset-4">
                                <div class="panel panel-default" style="margin-top:10px">
                                    <div class="panel-heading text-center" style="font-size:15px;font-weight:bold; background-color:#4D94CE; color:white;"><i class="fa fa-users" style="font-size:x-large"></i><br />Panel Heading</div>
                                    <div class="panel-body text-center" style="height:60px;font-size:15px">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover title" data-content="A larger popover to demonstrate the max-width of the Bootstrap popover.">Large popover</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover title" data-content="A larger popover to demonstrate the max-width of the Bootstrap popover.">Large popover</button>
                    </section>
                       </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

**JQuery code for bootstrap popover**

```
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
            placement: 'top',
            trigger: 'hover'
        });
```

**Popover outside the panel (This works great)**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover title" data-content="A larger popover to demonstrate the max-width of the Bootstrap popover.">Large popover</button>
```

Comment: it works. This is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4wzuktm6/1/)

Comment: Updated my question. This does not work

Comment: Please try this

Comment: it works [fine](https://jsfiddle.net/a3Lcpow2/1/)